# Move single message into different queue using github.com/fmtn/a

Tags: jms

I have an JMS setup using ActiveMQ 5.13.4 with several dead letter queues (DLQ), and I want to move specific messages from the DLQ back into the original queue so that my app can process them again once the original error condition has been resolved.

I have been using a JMS utility called [A](https://github.com/fmtn/a) which can move multiple messages from one queue to another with the `--move-queue` option. This works very well in that you can either move all messages are just a certain number with the `--count` option e.g. This moves 10 message from DLQ1 to DLQ2

```
a.bat -b tcp://192.168.1.100:61616 --count 10 --move-queue DLQ1 DLQ2 -j -U admin -P admin
10 msgs moved from DLQ1 to DLQ2
Operation completed in 172ms (excluding connect)
```

What I want to do is to move a specific message using its JMS Message ID from one queue to another.  The `--get` command does find the required message but it consumes it so it is gone from that point e.g. get a single message on queue A1.

```
a.bat --broker tcp://192.168.1.100:61616 --user admin --pass admin --get A1 "JMSMessageID=ID:app02-49195-1696991438815-4:104:1:1:1" -j
-----------------
Message Headers
  JMSCorrelationID: null
  JMSExpiration: 1970 01 01 01:00:00
  JMSDeliveryMode: persistent
  JMSMessageID: ID:app02-49195-1696991438815-4:104:1:1:1
  JMSPriority: 5
  JMSTimestamp: 2023 11 08 07:24:20
  JMSType: null
  JMSDestination: queue://A1
  JMSRedelivered: false
  JMSReplyTo: Not set
Message Properties
Payload:
message
Operation completed in 15ms (excluding connect)
```

There is a `--selector` option which does find the required message but I can't seem to get it to work with the `--move-queue option` - it says the operation completed but it is using the jms header ID as the destination queue name ?? e.g.

```
a.bat --broker tcp://192.168.1.100:61616 --user admin --pass admin --move-queue A1 --selector A1 "JMSMessageID=ID:app02-49195-1696991438815-4:106:1:1:1" --move-queue A2 -j
0 msgs moved from A1 to JMSMessageID=ID:app02-49195-1696991438815-4:106:1:1:1
Operation completed in 125ms (excluding connect)
```

I think what is happening is that the `--selector` option is unable to filter based on the `JMSMessageID`, therefore the `--move-queue` option and is not doing anything. Does `--selector` option actually work with the JMS header info?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: its an old version - 5.13.4 (so not the new Artemis version)

Comment: That's too bad. ActiveMQ Artemis has a feature built in where you can "retry" a message from a DLQ so that it is sent back to the original queue.

Comment: I think I have actually cracked the issue now. There were 2 problems.
1. When specifying the JMSMessageID with --selector you have to lead and end with double quotes around the JMSMessageID and the ID itself has to be surrounded with single quotes inside of the double ones e.g. --selector "JMSMessageID='ID:app02-49195-1696991438815-4:128:1:1:12'"
If you don't do that it will not find the right message.
2. You can use the --selector command as part of the source queue e.g. --move-queue A1 --selector "JMSMessageID='ID:49195-1696991438815-4:128:1:1:12'" A2 --jms-headers

Answer (score 0):

I think I have actually cracked the issue now. There were 2 problems.

1. When specifying the JMSMessageID with --selector you have to lead and end with double quotes around the JMSMessageID and the ID itself has to be surrounded with single quotes inside of the double ones e.g.

> --selector "JMSMessageID='ID:app02-49195-1696991438815-4:128:1:1:12'"

If you don't do that it will not find the right message.

2. You can use the --selector command as part of the source queue e.g.

> --move-queue A1 --selector "JMSMessageID='ID:49195-1696991438815-4:128:1:1:12'" A2
> --jms-headers

Therefore the final command to move a single message using its JMSMessageID from a queue called A1 to another queue called A2 would be as follows.

> a.bat --broker tcp://192.168.1.100:61616 -U admin -P admin
> --move-queue A1 --selector "JMSMessageID='ID:49195-1696991438815-4:128:1:1:12'" A2 --jms-headers
> 1 msgs moved from A1 to A2
> Operation completed in 141ms (excluding connect)